# Software to recover SQL Server 2005 ldf file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transaction-log

Can Anyone tell me how to recover database in SQL Server 2005 using free (i mean not shareware) software that only using ldf file?

Thanxs before

Comment: I may be rusty, but isn't ldf just the log file and no data?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304824/is-there-a-way-to-restore-a-db-in-sql-2005-from-ldf-only

Answer (score 2):

If you **only** have the LDF file (the transaction log), there's no way you can recover the database......

The transaction log file - as its name implies - only contains the transactions that were run against your database in the past - since the last full backup of the log file. It does **not** contain the actual data that's stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. I'm deadly serious.

Your only option is to restore from a backup, which you have of course...?

Answer (score 0):

Your question so much off, that I can only "point a finger to the moon", so **[start reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477(SQL.90).aspx)**.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction log (the ldf) is just a file of transactions and the changes made by them all. Unless this transaction log contains every transaction since the very beginning of the original database's existence, it simply doesn't contain the information needed to even hypothetically recreate the source DB.
Even if it did contain every change, I'm not aware of any software (especially not free software) that could recreate it.